# tensorflow_dataset assertion error with "KITTI" dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-datasets

It's a few days that I don't know how to solve this error.

Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf               # 2.3.0
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds    # 3.1.0
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load(
    "kitti",
    split=['train', 'test'], 
    data_dir='../../tensorflow_datasets',
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True
)
```

and every time I execute on Jupyter Notebook the `tfds.load()` function it throws this error

[image]
[image]
[image]

I also tried with a different piece of code, but with the same result, in particular, I've tried with

```
import tensorflow as tf               # 2.3.0
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds    # 3.1.0
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

builder = tfds.builder(name='kitti', data_dir='../../tensorflow_datasets')
builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir='../../tensorflow_datasets/downloads')

ds = builder.as_dataset()
```

but it throws the same error (I think that `tds.load(...)` call itself the builder) on function `builder.download_and_prepare(...)`.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but have you checked if you have enough memory to load at least 17 GiB of data? Or if you have enough storage space? I ran the same code in Google Colab and had no issues.

Comment: I also tried with Google Colab and it works good. The storage space is not a problem,  I have around 700 GB of space available. I don't know why, but only in jupyter notebook it has some problems. I'm using conda environment, to open Jupyter.